# FormBuilder - Custom Validator - Many fields and promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to validate my form with a custom validator which using many fields and .. using a Promise in my validation function ...

I write this code :

```
this.saisieForm = this.fb.group({
  'refUnique': ['', [Validators.required]],
  'refLettrage': ['', [Validators.required],ValidateRefLettrage(this.operationService)],
  'typeOperation': ['', [Validators.required, ValidateTypeOperation]],
  'codeProduitGestion': new FormControl(''),
  'sectionPatri': new FormControl(''),
  'compteDispo': ['', [Validators.required, ValidateCompteDispo]],
  'dateOperation': ['', [Validators.required,ValidateDate(this.envService.config.app.dateOperationMinJour,this.envService.config.app.dateOperationMaxJour)]],
  'dateValeur': ['',[Validators.required,ValidateDate(this.envService.config.app.dateValeurMinJour,this.envService.config.app.dateValeurMaxJour)]],
  'montant': ['', Validators.required],
  'commentaire': new FormControl('')
}, {
  validator: [ValidatorsSaisies.validateMontant(Validators.required, ['montant', "compteDispo"]),ValidatorsSaisies.validateDoublons2(this.operationService)]
});
```

and for the custom validator :

```
  static validateDoublons2(operationService:OperationService) {
  return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('myAsyncValidator finished!')
        setTimeout(() => group.updateValueAndValidity())

        operationService.checkDoublons(
          group.get("refUnique").value,
          group.get("dateValeur").value,
          group.get("dateValeur").value,
          group.get("montant").value,
          group.get("montant").value,
          group.get("compteDispo").value.taParamDevise,
          group.get("refLettrage").value,
          group.get("typeOperation").value.sens,
          "200")
          .then((data) => {
            test = true;
            resolve(null);

          })
          .catch((err) => {
            resolve({validRefLettrage: true})
          });

      }, 2500);
    })


  }
}
```

The problem is ... the call of validateDoublons2 loop indefinitely ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `updateValueAndValidty` in your custom validator, which recalculates the value and validation status. So when you call that, your custom validator is refiring, causing an infinite loop. I don't see that you would need this at all, but if you are using it, do...

```
updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false})
```

This means that function is not emitting event and your custom validator will not refire after calling it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , its the same attitude with emitEvent false. I use this solution because a have the same problem mentionned here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14542.

Comment: Why are you using Promises by the way? Why not observables? :)